# How to Group IQueryable Method

Tags: linq, api, model-view-controller, onion-architecture

I want to group List to avoid recurrence records in screen

I want to have inner join with SiteToEmp which need to be grouded 
As i have an IQueryable Method Which return list from data base another table (SiteToEmp )have relation that can record more than one record for the same foreign key (SiteID) when i do join relation i have to use grouping by the primary key which fail to convert

```
  protected override IQueryable<SiteViewModel> BuildQuery(byte tab, byte? range, DateTime? start, DateTime? end, string role)
    {
        var source = typeof(Site).Name;
        if (range != null && range != 10 && range != 0)
            RequestUtil.RequestRangeFilter(UnitOfWork, range.Value, Parms.CompanyId, out start, out end);

        var query =
            (from site in UnitOfWork.SiteRepository.GetAll()
             join lookup in UnitOfWork.LookUpRepository.Find(l => l.CodeName == "Sitetype")
                 on site.SiteType equals lookup.CodeId into ldg
             from lookup in ldg.DefaultIfEmpty()

             join lookuptitle in UnitOfWork.LookUpTitlesRepository.Find(l =>
                     l.CodeName == "Sitetype" && l.Culture == Parms.Language)
                 on site.SiteType equals lookuptitle.CodeId into ltdg
             from lookuptitle in ltdg.DefaultIfEmpty()

             join district in UnitOfWork.DistrictRepository.GetAll()
                    on site.DistrictId equals district.Id into g2
             from district in g2.DefaultIfEmpty()

             join city in UnitOfWork.CityRepository.GetAll()
                 on site.CityId equals city.Id into g3
             from city in g3.DefaultIfEmpty()

             join country in UnitOfWork.CountryRepository.GetAll()
                 on site.CountryId equals country.Id into g4
             from country in g4.DefaultIfEmpty()

             join siteToEmp in UnitOfWork.SiteToEmployeesRepository.GetAll()
                 on site.Id equals siteToEmp.SiteId into g
             from siteToEmp in g.DefaultIfEmpty()

             join employee in UnitOfWork.EmployeeViewRepository.GetEmployeesByCompanyId(Parms.CompanyId,
                     Parms.Language)
                 on siteToEmp.EmpId equals employee.EmpId into g1
             from employee in g1.DefaultIfEmpty()

             select new SiteViewModel
             {
                 Id = site.Id,
                 Code = site.Code,
                 Name = site.Name,
                 LocalName = site.Name,
                 TimeZone = site.TimeZone,
                 Latitude = site.Latitude,
                 Longitude = site.Longitude,
                 Address = site.Address1,
                 City = city.Name,
                 District = district.Name,
                 Country = country.Name,
                 SiteTypeName = (lookuptitle == null ? lookup.Name : lookuptitle.Title),
                 SiteToEmployeesList = employee.EmpName,
                 ContactPerson = site.ContactPerson,
                 Email = site.Email,
                 Mobile = site.Telephone
             });//.GroupBy(k => k.Id).ToList(); 

        //var results = query.GroupBy(x => x.Id).ToList();
        return query;
    }
```

Cannot implicitly convert type System.Linq.IQueryable to 'System.Linq.IQueryable'
 An explicit conversion exists

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to return the first item of each group:

```
var results = query.GroupBy(x => x.Id)
    .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault())
    .ToList();
```

I don't know if it matters, but this will return a "random" employee when there are more that match the join. You may want to take control over which employee is returned by ordering the group, for example:

```
...
.Select(g => g.OrderBy(e => e.SiteToEmployeesList).FirstOrDefault())
```

By the way, `SiteToEmployeesList` doesn't contain a list but just one name. It's better to use a more appropriate property name.

Another remark: try to use navigation properties instead of all these verbose joins. I.e. properties like `site.District` referring to a `District` object, or `site.SiteToEmployees` containing a list of `SiteToEmployee` objects, etc.

Answer (score 0):

it was Solved by Changes Method Type To :
     public async Task>> GetSiteList(byte tab, byte? range, DateTime? start,
            DateTime? end,string role){//////}
insted of :
      protected override IQueryable BuildQuery(byte tab, byte? range, DateTime? start, DateTime? end, string role)
    {////////}

Answer (score 0):

It Was Solved by Changes Method Type To :

```
    public async Task<List<SiteViewModel>> GetSiteList(byte tab, byte? range, DateTime? start, DateTime? end,string role){......}
```

Instead Of :

```
    protected override IQueryable BuildQuery(byte tab, byte? range, DateTime? start, DateTime? end, string role){.....}
```

Comment: That code doesn't compile. What should `Task>>` be?

Comment: `Task<List<SiteViewModel>>`

Comment: Well, that doesn't solve anything. It only makes the code asynchronous, but you still don't return the correct type. You still need to convert `IGrouping` into `List<SiteViewModel>`, which my code does.

Comment: i tried this  `public async Task<List<IGrouping<int, SiteViewModel>>> GetSiteList(byte tab, byte? range, DateTime? start,
            DateTime? end, string role)` and it had already return the list grouping but the issue is in view as view appear like the list have no data how it have data and i use Json to send the list

Comment: Yeah, that just kicks the can down the road. Now the caller has to unwrap the grouping.

Comment: ok please how did you return `Task<List<IGrouping<int, model>>> `in your  view

Comment: Just don't. I don't understand the trouble. I offered you a method to return what you want to return, what's wrong with it?

Comment: the method is doing well the issue is in view it can't accept `Task<List<IGrouping<int, model>>>`

Comment: My code doesn't return a grouping! It returns `List<SiteViewModel>`, or the `Task` version of it if you make it async.

Comment: I tried to use 
`@model IEnumerable<System.Linq.IGrouping<int, SiteViewModel>>` and
`@model IEnumerable<SiteViewModel>` but twice were useless

Comment: Then something in the view code isn't right. My method returns what you need, `List<SiteViewModel>`, which is `IEnumerable<SiteViewModel`. If the view has problems with that you should ask a new question if you cant figure it out.